# Issue for changing default URL PhpMyAdmin with Nginx

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

I tried to change the default URL of PhpMyAdmin so instead of accessing it through `test.com/phpmyadmin` I would do `test.com/admin123`

I tried this tutorial [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-1-%E2%80%94-install-phpmyadmin) without success, I created a new symlink

#### Symlink

`admin123 -> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/`

#### Configuration

```
server {

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location /phpmyadmin {
      root /usr/share/;
      index index.php;
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

      location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(doc|sql|setup)/ {
        deny all;
      }

      location ~ /phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      }
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
```

}

#### Issues

I can still access normally `/phpmyadmin` and not `/admin123`. I restored `Nginx` and emptied my cache

Comment: Create a location block with /admin123 and inside that rewrite rule to phpmyadmjn

Comment: It does work, I can now access phpmyadmin with both url, but I'd like to prevent access from phpmyadmin. The only working URL should be /admin123. Am I missing something else ?

Comment: Remove the phpmyadmin location block and set root in admin123 block to phpmyadmin location.

Comment: Would you mind to post a full example, cause I tried several things but now I have a white page when accessing /admin123